# No partition found error when installing an OS on Dell Poweredge with RAID

Tags: windows, raid, dell, bios

I have three Dell 1850 rack servers:

- One has 3 GB of RAM and two 73GB HDD's.
- Two others have 6 GB RAM and each of them has two 73GB HDD's.

I am currently trying to install an OS on them, but when I boot with Windows XP setup it gives me an error saying that no partition is found. I have set these drives up in RAID on the server and I put them online, so they should be working fine, but they're not.

What can I do? I have no clue as to if it's the BIOS or the RAID controller within it.

Comment: It's probably something about not having the OS drivers for the RAID card.

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely be a missing RAID driver.

The 1850 normally came with a PERC 3 or 4 - the driver is [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukbsdt1/DriverDetails?DriverId=8KN93&FileId=2731108926&DriverName=LSI%20Logic%20PERC3%2FDCL%2C%20PERC3%2FDC%2C%20PERC3%2FQC%2C%20PERC3%2FSC%2C%20PERC%204%2FDi%2C%20CERC%20ATA%20100%2C%20PERC%204%2FSC%2C%20PERC%204%2FDC%2C%20PERC%204e%2FDC%2C%20Perc%204e%2FDi%2C%20PERC%204e%2FSi%2C%20v.6.46.2.32%2C%20A05&productCode=poweredge-1850&urlProductCode=False).

The above driver is for 32 bit Windows, for 64 bit use [this one](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukbsdt1/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=KDYKD&FileId=2731092502&productCode=poweredge-1850&urlProductCode=False).

You will need to run this and expand it to a floppy then when prompted press F6 while loading Windows.

It is possible this driver may not work with XP as it is intended for Server 2003 although it probably will.

If you don't have a floppy drive in the servers, either try a USB drive, or slipstream the driver onto an XP CD. Note, Nlite makes this very easy but the results are not supported by Microsoft.

If you have a recent Dell XP SP3 CD give that a shot as I think they may already have PERC 3/4 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Check Dell site for an OEM driver that you can slipstream onto your Installation Media. You'd probably need the 3rd party inf driver in order for (atleast XP) the Operating System to detect it and be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark a virtual disk as bootable in the RAID controller.

`Configure` -> `Specify Boot Drive`

> Select this option to specify a logical drive as the boot drive on this adapter.

[RAID Configuration and Management](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/perc4e/en/ug/chap4.htm#1069602)

Answer (score 0):

As most have already said, you need to load your PERC drivers. If you do not have a floppy drive, or would like to avoid it, download this utility from Dell: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails?driverId=R146318

Burn it, boot it, and navigate through the menu's towards Operating System Installation. You will be prompted to insert the OS disk, and drivers should be injected.